# Python regex to match all occurrences between curly brackets, not just the last occurence

Tags: python, regex

In my Python code, I have the following string:

`Here is my string with "\"The Address\", I want to replace only the selection between the brackes: {Here is my string between \"The Address\" and \"something\" else}. Thank you!`

I would like to replace ALL occurrences of `\"` that occur ONLY between curly brackets with `"`.  So my desired result is

`Here is my string with "\"The Address\", I want to replace only the selection between the brackes: {Here is my string between "The Address" and "something" else}. Thank you!`

I'm trying `r'({.*)(\\")(.*})'` with a substitution of `\1"\3` as given here: https://regex101.com/r/NWSDS6/1

However that is only selecting/replacing the very last `\"` , how do I select/replace ALL of the occurrences between the curly braces?

EDIT after comment: Here is a variation of the string with an extra curly bracket after the word "replace":

`Here is my string with "\"The Address\", I want to replace} only the selection between the brackes: {Here is my string between \"The Address\" and \"something\" else}. Thank you!`

In this variation, the first two occurrences are selected however I would like them to be omitted as they do not occur BETWEEN TWO curly brackets.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this solution using `lambda`:

```bash
s = r'Here is my string with "\"The Address\", I want to replace} only the selection between the brackes: {Here is my string between \"The Address\" and \"something\" else}. Thank you!'

s = re.sub(r'{[^}]*}', lambda m: m.group().replace(r'\"', '"'), s)

console.log(s)
```

**Output:**

```bash
Here is my string with "\"The Address\", I want to replace} only the selection between the brackes: {Here is my string between "The Address" and "something" else}. Thank you!
```

Here:

- `{[^}]*}` matches string between `{...}`
- `m.group().replace(r'\"', '"')` replaces all `\"` with `"` inside the matched text.

Comment: `s.replace('\"', '"')` will do the same. is there reason why you use lambda? just curious sir.

Comment: `s.replace('\"', '"')` will do the replacements anywhere not just inside the `{...}` substring as desired by OP

Comment: Thank you!  This almost works for me but it fails when I have an extra curly bracket at the start - please see what I have added to the OP under EDIT.

Comment: Try my updated answer now